# How To Use Module Exports Properly In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, export

I just started learning JS and when i try to export a simple function inside a file called function_module.js using this code

```
module.exports.squareFunction = function(nb){
return nb * nb ;
}
```

in other file in the same directory i tried to import the function using this code

```
const importedfun = require('./function_module.js');
console.log(importedfun(5));
```

i got this error

```
JavaScript\CodeAcademy\module\test_module.js:2
console.log(importedfun(5));
        ^

TypeError: importedfun is not a function
at Object.<anonymous>
```

can anyone tell me what is my fault ?

Comment: try module.exports = {squareFunction}, and then const {squareFunction} = require('./function_module.js')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing `module.exports.squareFunction`, you create a `named export` using `commonjs` syntax. You can either require it in another module using brackets `{nameOfYourExportedFunction}` or do a default export instead.

**Named export**

```js
module.exports.squareFunction = function(nb){
    return nb * nb ;
}

//////

// Notice the brackets wrapping the function
const {squareFunction} = require('./function_module.js');
console.log(squareFunction(5));
```

**Default export**

```js
module.exports = function(nb){
    return nb * nb ;
}

//////

// You can name it however you want since it will refer to the default export
const importedFun = require('./function_module.js');
console.log(importedfun(5));
```